# joomla - forgot password page saying invalid email

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a user who registered with an email like "word+word@email.com" it allowed the + sign when registering but it is not allowing him to retrieve his password from the forgot password page. The email input line goes read and gets the "invalid" class when the plus sign is entered. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_your_admin_password?) for that. You have to have access to your database, though

Also, most of all mail services does not support letters like `+`, `_`, `-` in the URL (mail address)

Comment: It is not an issue with resetting the password itself. It is that it allowed the email with a plus sign in the first place and now it is not letting him retrieve his password with that email.

Comment: You're using the 1.5 version of Joomla! so there shouldn't be any problems. Maybe the server doesn't have access to the web?

Comment: How are you actually trying to get an e-mail from joomla?

Comment: Yes, the sign has been up for over year and have had no other problems than this. I am thinking it is reg ex issue that is different from registration page and forgot password. I will investigate more.

Comment: if this is the first time you're having problems with sending e-mail: Perhaps you're having the same problem as this [post](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=259764). But, I think that the user have to change his/her e-mail address. Most of all mail services does not support letters like '+', '_', '-' in the URL

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think that the "+" slipped through. I have never seen an email address that has a plus in it. Thanks for the help.